# Delay with disable button in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying that if you insert a new product My app should have a delay (2seg), then My Button was disabled until that my server accept or refuse the insert.

I have 2 problems :

1º TypeError: this.http.post(...).delay is not a function . 
2º I can't change status my form for disabled my button .

```
insert(formModifyConfig: NgForm) {

        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/insert';


        this.service.insert(url , this.product).subscribe(param => {

            let params = JSON.parse(param);
            this.myMessage.success = params.success;
            this.myMessage.message =  params.message;

            if ( this.myMessage.success) {
                this.openModalUpdate = false;
                this.confirmedServer = true;
            } else {
                this.errorServer = true;
            }

        },  error => {
            formModifyConfig.status = false; --> Second error.
           // formModifyConfig.form.invalid = true;  --> Second error.
            this.errorServer = true;
            this.myMessage.message = "Error Server";
        });
   }
```

//Service Angular

```
  insert(url , product) {
    return this.http.post(url, product , { responseType: 'text'}).delay(2000); --> First error.
  }
```

I search that While my server try insert (true o false) My Button the Angular should be disabled until that my server answer

html:

```
<form #insertConfig="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="insert(insertConfig)" class="compact" novalidate>
    <clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="openModalUpdate" [clrModalStaticBackdrop]="true">

        <h3 class="modal-title">Insert{{ staticParamName }}</h3>

        <div class="modal-body">

                <clr-alert [clrAlertType]="'alert-danger'" *ngIf="errorServer">
                        <clr-alert-item>
                            <span class="alert-text">
                               {{ this.myMessage.message }}
                            </span>
                        </clr-alert-item>
                     </clr-alert>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <label for="nameParameter">Name: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" id="nameParameter" name="nameParameter" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="insert.parameter" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <label for="description">Description: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" id="description" name="description" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="insert.description">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="insertConfig.form.invalid">Insert</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="openModalUpdate = false">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </clr-modal>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a example of how would i have done it considering above usecase,

1. create a Boolean variable on your component, let's say serviceCalled = false;
2. change your submit html as

   Insert
3. In component method

   insert( formModifyConfig: NgForm ){

   ```
           serviceCalled=true;

           const url = 'http://localhost:8080/insert';

           this.service.insert(url , this.product).subscribe(param => {
           serviceCalled=false;
           ....
           },(error)=>{
           serviceCalled=false;
           }
           )
   ```

Comment: But if I do, the button is never enabled to "insert". I need to do checks on my forms (all entries are required).It
Should be disabled because all checks were empty, then If all is correct, button insert is correct, and I access to function, but with your code never access to function or my button always is enabled without check inputs.

Comment: I don't know if you change your button HTML to <button type="submit" (click)="insert()"class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="insertConfig.form.invalid||serviceCalled">Insert</button>, If your form is valid, it would ENABLE the submit because of 'OR' operator. then when enabled and clicked it would call insert function and it would disable it untill response OR error occurs